# Creating AD user accounts for workstations in different sites

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, user-accounts

I am intending to set up user and administrative accounts for all workstations in my company (a small one). The company has 3 offices located in different locations, connecting to different Internet subscription lines.

I would however like to have a single server (running on Windows Server 2012) located at the main office, with the user accounts controlled by AD in the server. Will it be possible for users from other site offices to login to the accounts created by the server, and to access files that are stored in the server? Will the server be still able to have control over access control and rights of users using computers in other offices?

I'm a beginner in server deployment and AD, so pardon me if I use some terms wrongly or sound amateurish. Any help on this is much appreciated, and do let me know if you require further details.

Thank you!

Comment: If the offices have network connectivity to each other (most likely via a VPN connection), then yes.

Comment: A single Domain Controller is NOT a recommended configuration. If that lone DC goes down, users cannot log on or access resources.

Comment: Users can log on with cached credentials.  Single DC is not good, but users can still log onto their workstation when it is down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is easily achievable, but you will need to do some research. AD is complex and there is no silver bullet for meeting everyone's requirements. One thing to bear in mind is connectivity - you mention that each site has it's own internet connectivity. Obviously it's a requirement that all these computers (workstations and server) can communicate with each other, so you need either a WAN or a VPN network.

It's also worth considering risk; Microsoft recommend a minimum of two Active Directory domain controllers per physical site. You need to bear in mind that if one of your sites loses its connection, they're potentially unable to log in to their computers until you resolve the issue. And if your server goes down, everyone across all sites are in trouble.

You also need to consider alternatives - given the above risks, have you considered using Azure and/or Office 365? This may provide you the functionality you need with built in redundancy and a lot of the overhead/maintenance/administration taken care of.

Finally, the best thing you can do is simulate and test this stuff. There are a lot of free virtualisation tools available (Hyper-V, VMWare, VirtualBox). That will let you build a virtual model of your network and scenario, to test it out before you deploy it.

Good luck! And always check back here (and elsewhere) with specific questions.

EDIT: I don't know what level your studies or experience are up to, but if you haven't already take a look at [Microsoft Virtual Academy](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/). It's free, and there's a lot of courses in there that will give you the skills you need to get this working, and probably help you in the rest of your day to day work as well.

Comment: I suggest that's not obvious unless you already know it. (Imagining: "Of course they can communicate - they have internet. Just point the computers at the server, right? Windows is secure. And what's a VPN?")